# Extract text by index from multiple classes, xpaths, or css selectors

Tags: python, selenium

The HTML I'm scraping has multiple classes of the same name. It looks like this:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count">56</span>

<span aria-hidden="true" class="v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count">45</span>

<span aria-hidden="true" class="v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count">10</span>
```

And so on...

I want to pull the 'innerText' ("56", "45", "10" respectively) from each of the first (20) instances of this class. My thought was that I could pull each by their index by using find_elements_by_xpath, find_elements_by_class_name, or find_elements_by_css_selector.

If I were to do it by css_selector, this is what I think it would look like:

```
likes1 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count > span:nth-of-type(1)")
likes2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count > span:nth-of-type(2)")
likes3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count > span:nth-of-type(3)")
```

And so on to (20)...

Before I start appending/printing the data, I also want to iterate these through a loop. If I'm fetching an individual element (by index), I don't understand why I need a loop if I didn't return a list, but that's another matter. So it would look like this:

```
for l1 in likes1:
     data.append({
     "Likes1": l1.text
     })
for l2 in likes2:
     data.append({
     "Likes2": l2.text
     })
for l3 in likes3:
     data.append({
     "Likes3": l3.text
     })
```

And so on down to l20.text...

```
print(data)
driver.close()
```

Since this is a long-scrolling page, I guess incorporating multiple window.scrolls or Keys.PAGE_DOWN will need to be there as well. Also another matter...

My question is: Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better/more efficient way, for example, without having to loop through each? Thanks in advance for telling me where I'm going wrong. These are the woes of growth!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using single loop instead of writing seperate loop for each class of elements. Please try like below,

```
allLikes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count")
    for i in allLikes
     data.append({
         element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count > span:nth-of-type("+i+")")
         "Likes"+i: element.text
         })
print(data)
driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error here: "element"+i  - I don't know enough to know how to fix it.

Comment: Also, @Nandan A, how would I stop at 20?

Comment: Updated the solution ... Can you try now?

Comment: No luck. Are you sure the "element" variable should be within data.append?

Comment: Ohh.. it should be outside..

Comment: Hm. I'm returning an empty array, which isn't making sense to me. No matter what I run, I still return empty. I've tried .text and .get_attribute('innerText') variations. I know the css_selector is correct. I've tried find_elements_by_class_name, too. I know the text exists that I want, still I can't seem to return anything

Answer (score 0):

if this class represent

```
v-align-middle social-details-social-counts__reactions-count
```

20 or more elements, and you only want to scrape 20 initial elements. Please use a **counter** with `find_elements`.

**Sample code  :**

```
counter = 1
data = []
likes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count")
for like in likes:
    if counter <= 20:
        print(like.text)
        data.append(like.text)
        counter = counter + 1
```

In case you do not wish to have counter and wants to scrape everything, please use :

```
data = []
likes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.v-align-middle.social-details-social-counts__reactions-count")
for like in likes:
     print(like.text)
     data.append(like.text)
     counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: I don't doubt this works, but it only returned the first three results. I'm not sure why that is.